# Ruby equivalent of PHP's $_GET

Tags: ruby, apache, cgi-bin

What is the bare minimum I need to require in Ruby (not Rails or any other framework) to easily obtain request data like GETs?

I would like to avoid having to use ruby on rails or any other framework to get this data, so the ideal answer wouldn't have a framework dependency.

My current setup has a ruby file (`script`) in a `cgi-bin` on apache (`site.com/script`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# bare minimum to output content
puts "Content-type: text/html"
puts

puts "it works!" #works fine.

# how would I obtain request data like GET parameters here
# for a url like site.com/script?hi=there
# in PHP, I would $_GET['hi']
```

Comment: What web framework are you using for Ruby?

Comment: How would you do this `without` a framework? (I updated the question)

Comment: What web server are you using (if it is Apache, what modules are you using for Ruby)? Ruby is not like PHP -- simply dropping the file in public_html won't work. You will need to run a webserver that can support serving Ruby files.

Comment: I'm just using a cgi-bin on apache. It's currently working, outputting html which is formed by this ruby script using `puts` after the content header. I just want to find out how to obtain GET data at the lowest level in ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, solved my problem using the CGI class.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html

```
require 'cgi'

cgi = CGI.new

cgi.params.each do |key, val|
   puts key
   puts val
end
```

so `site.com/script?hi=there` would output `hi\nthere`

Comment: Considering marking this as answer. You'll get a sweet badge and this question won't be considered open!

Comment: it makes me wait 2 days before I can mark my own as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Please don't do this without a framework. There are some super lightweight ones like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) that do as little as possible to ensure you have the support you need to do this correctly. CGI died in the 1990s and doesn't need to come back now.

To write a Sinatra application you basically define a method, then deploy it to your server. Sure, you may grumble about how much *work* that is, but if you don't have a proper deployment procedure you're in trouble before you even start.

Ruby has a lot of infrastructure built up around things like Rack that hook into Apache through modules like [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) that do a lot more than `cgi-bin` ever did without all the risks associated with it.

A typical Sinatra app looks like:

```
get '/example/:id' do
  "Example #{params[:id]}!"
end
```

There's really nothing to it and it ends up being a *lot* less work than the old CGI way.

Comment: my reason for asking was purely academic. Just learning the core functionality of Ruby is still very valuable. Thanks for recommending Passenger btw

Answer (score 2):

If your web server is calling the script as a [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) program, then the contents would be in the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable, accessible through the [`ENV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ENV.html) object. Without a framework, you will have to parse this into individual name-value pairs to get something like PHP's `$_GET`.

Because Ruby is a general-purpose programming language, it doesn't have core classes and methods for dealing with HTTP requests or the CGI environment. That is why it is recommended to use a framework, such as Ruby on Rails, to handle the protocol-level parsing and setup. There are too many places to make mistakes, and it is not worth reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is incorrect. Ruby's core library includes [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) that can do a lot of this for you, but can be obnoxious to use for simple things.

Comment: @tadman Yes, which is why I edited to say "core" instead of "built-in". The design is still different from PHP where everything is built-in to the language without `require`s or `include`s (a terrible design, IMHO).

Comment: Well, it does have "core" classes and methods. It doesn't have much of anything built-in. Nearly all elements of Ruby outside of Object, Fixnum and a select number of fundamental types are loaded in dynamically. The distinction is meaningless, though. Net::HTTP ships with Ruby and can be expected to exist on any installation.